Audio artifacts when recording in a virtual machine
I have a strange problem when recording audio in a virtual machine, which is that a lot of the time the recorded audio has about 100ms of what sounds like leftover audio (sometimes just noise, but often I recognize my own voice from a previous recording). This is with a setup that worked before upgrading from Linux Mint 21 to 22, ie starting using pipewire.
I narrate audio books and am forced (by my employer) to use an old program that only works reliably on windows xp. Therefore I use virtualbox (7.0.16) to run xp in a virtual machine. This has worked fine until I upgraded Mint from 21 to 22. Now sometimes (about half of the time when I do a specific thing that I need to do quite often...) when I record i get something like 1/10th of a second of trash audio at the beginning of the sound file, and I can work around it, but it takes some extra work that I would like to be rid of.
Sofar I've tried increasing alsa headroom (https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/pipewire/pipewire/-/wikis/Troubleshooting#stuttering-audio-in-virtual-machine) and have been experimenting with different buffer sizes, but the problem persists.
I think I will try downgrading from VBox 7 to 6.1, since that was what I was using before upgrading Mint (the virtual machine itself is the same, I exported it before the upgrade), but any other suggestions are most welcome too!

Sorry the Mint OS is not supported on this Ubuntu only support site.
